# Failed to validate trajectory after updating moveit (Feb 2017)

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I am very new to ROS and i'm currently working on gazebo and moveit on ros indigo.
I am currently using the "Autonomous-Flight-ROS" code written by AlessioTonioni. Before updating moveit, everything works well. After updating, I have no problem planning a motion but the problem happens when i execute my planning from moveit to gazebo, it gives the error: "Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s".

I'm currently using ros indigo, gazebo 2.2.6, moveit last update (Feb 2017), ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

In the terminal, when i try to plan and execute a valid state, it shows

```
[ INFO] [1487385467.586393924, 55.384000000]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[ INFO] [1487385467.632584405, 55.416000000]: No optimization objective specified, defaulting to PathLengthOptimizationObjective
[ INFO] [1487385467.633476818, 55.417000000]: Planner configuration 'Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]' will use planner 'geometric::PRMstar'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[ INFO] [1487385467.648647637, 55.427000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1487385467.648978360, 55.427000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1487385467.649068794, 55.427000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1487385467.649106579, 55.427000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1487385467.649145390, 55.427000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1487385467.651254216, 55.428000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1487385467.652344408, 55.428000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1487385467.653093549, 55.429000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1487385467.659354421, 55.432000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1487385472.650616281, 58.683000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 1391 states
[ INFO] [1487385472.650772184, 58.684000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 1274 states
[ INFO] [1487385472.650862388, 58.684000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 1524 states
[ INFO] [1487385472.651784028, 58.685000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 1402 states
[ INFO] [1487385472.652006827, 58.685000000]: ProblemDefinition: Adding approximate solution from planner PathHybridization
[ INFO] [1487385472.652064502, 58.685000000]: ParallelPlan::solve(): Solution found by one or more threads in 5.002876 seconds
[ INFO] [1487385475.181260991, 60.603000000]: Received new trajectory execution service request...
[ WARN] [1487385476.487933898, 61.609000000]: Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s
[ INFO] [1487385476.488162318, 61.609000000]: Execution completed: ABORTED
```

The rqt_graph is attached below
[rosgraph.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14873856542107714.png)

I will be grateful if someone could help me on this problem. Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254927/failed-to-validate-trajectory-after-updating-moveit-(feb-2017)/) by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-17**:
Please don't use screenshots for text. If you ever remove the screenshot from your google drive, this question becomes worthless. You could easily copy-paste the console text into your question, and use the *Preformatted Text* button to format it properly.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-17**:
I've also given you enough karma to attach the `rqt_graph` sshot to this image.

Note btw that as you have it now it's way too small. You might want to change that.

**Comment by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on 2017-02-17**:
Thank you so much! I had edited my question accordingly. Thanks !!

**Comment by [pyni_sjtu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28882/pyni_sjtu/) on 2017-04-20**:
你好，我和你遇到了一样的问题，请问你的问题解决了么？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your Gazebo setup seems to be incomplete.
Nobody publishes to the `/joint_states` topic and most likely a gazebo plugin should do that.

Addition: Be aware that if trajectory start-state validation does not make sense for your use-case,
you can also just disable it by putting this into your moveit_config's `launch/trajectory_execution.launch.xml`:

`<param name="trajectory_execution/allowed_start_tolerance" value="0.0"/>`

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on 2017-02-24**:
Thanks for the help! I installed the plugin by running `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-gazebo-plugins` . Now the gazebo published to `/joint_states` and `/joint_states` publishes to `/move_group`
But after installing the plugin, Rviz crashes when executing the planned path.

**Comment by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on 2017-02-24**:
[ INFO] [1487855801.224731980, 65.203000000]: Received new trajectory execution service request...
[move_group-1] process has died [pid 3299, exit code -11,